# Electronic authorization for US passport holder born in Russia

Tags: visas, us-citizens, mexico

I have a one-year old son. He was born in Russia, but has already an American passport. He also currently lives in Russia. Does I need to fill out an electronic authorization form for him to travel to Mexico. 
Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

No. As a US citizen, your son has visa-free access to Mexico for up to 180 days. See [Visa policy of Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Mexico) for more information.

If your son has any other citizenships (like Russian for example, but you didn't say either way), that doesn't matter if he enters Mexico using a US passport.